# Batch script to Queue the builds in tfs 2015/2017

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I was trying to execute builds using a Batch script, I wrote one but getting this error:

> please define the Build definition name. tfsbuild start /collection:https://tfs.prod.dcx.int.bell.ca/tfs/bellca/Consumer/builds/All Definitions/{Release)/{Project-name}/{Build definition name}

How can can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tfsbuild` command line tool is only for XAML builds. For modern builds, you'll need to use the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) or the C# wrapper for the REST API.

The documentation has good examples, but basically `POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}`

with an appropriate body:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "id": 25
  },
  "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
  "parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"true\",\"BuildConfiguration\":\"debug\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"x64\"}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just as Daniel said, you need to use the REST API, See [Queue-a-build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build).

You could simply use below PowserShell script to queue the builds (Just replace the params accordingly):

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$BuildDefinitionId = "34",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
  {
  "definition": {
    "id": $BuildDefinitionId
  },

  "parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"true\",\"BuildConfiguration\":\"debug\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"x64\"}"
}
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$($collectionurl)/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Comment: Hi, I made build.bat file using your script.When run got many errors.

Comment: @Ayush It's not .bat script, you need to create a PowerShell file, just copy and past the script and replace the arguments accordingly then save it to a `*.ps1` file. Then run the PS script.

Comment: have less knowledge, still in a learning phase. Your help is much appreciated. Will try and let you know any issues.

Comment: One more thing our builds are in XAML so shall I change this json to xaml ??

Comment: when try to use xaml in place of json getting this below error

Comment: CreatexamlBody : The term 'CreatexamlBody' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:29 char:9
+ $xaml = CreatexamlBody
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CreatexamlBody:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:32 char:11
+ $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $xaml -ContentType "app ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-Re 
   stMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestM 
   ethodCommand